# CSV file - how to limit fields length using regexp in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, csv, text-parsing

I'm parsing a semicolon separated CSV file where the line looks as follows

```
firstField;secondField;thirdField;fourth very long field which I need to truncate;fifth very long field which I need to truncate"
```

I need to truncate all fields to 10 characters

I'm able to truncate it field by field as in

```
open my $input, "<", "inputFile.txt" or die "Can't open the inputFile.txt";
while (my $line = <$input>){
     chomp($line);
     my @fields = split(';',$line);
     for $field (@fields){
         $field =~ s/.{10}\K.*// if ((defined $field) && (length $field > 10));
         }
     }
```

Is there any way to have a regexp, which will achieve that lets say on line level ?
something like

```
$line = s/;.{10}\K.*;?//g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be so complicated. Use the features of Perl and
only remove anything over 10 characters. No need for a range like {1,10}.

Slurp the whole file in, do the substitution on the whole file.
Makes life easier.

`$csv_str =~ s/(?m)(?:^|;)[^;\n]{10}\K[^;\n]+//g;`

```
 (?m)           # Multi-line mode
 (?: ^ | ; )    # BOL (beginning of line) or semi-colon
 [^;\n]{10}     # 10 chars, not semi-colon nor linebreak
 \K             # Clear the match buffer of all previous data
 [^;\n]+        # This is to be gotten rid of...
                # 1 or more not semi-colon nor linebreak
                # On to the next match
```

Matches:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 21 , len 1 ) 
d  

-----------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 44 , len 37 ) 
y long field which I need to truncate  

-----------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 92 , len 37 ) 
 long field which I need to truncate"
```

Comment: how do I " slurp " whole file in ?

Comment: `$/ = undef; my $csv_str = <$fh>;` or use the slurp package.

Comment: won't it hurt my memory? Some of files I'm parsing are 10M+.

Comment: btw. forgot to mention it earlier, Your regexp is something I was looking for. Although I don't understand it completely yet :)

Comment: Long gone are the days where 10 megabytes means anything. Added some comments to the regex.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use a regex like this:

```
/(^|;)(([^;]{1,10})([^;]*))/g
```

With substitution `$3`.

[**`[Regex Demo]`**](https://regex101.com/r/cB2fK7/2)

Comment: so the code would look like $line =~ s/(^|;)(([^;]{1,10})([^;]*))/$3/gm ; ?

Answer (score 2):

Does it need to be done as a regex? I think I'd put a map in your `split` line and use `substr`.

```
my @fields = 
  map { length > 10 ? substr($_, 0, 10) : $_ }
  split(/;/,$line);
```

That feels more maintainable to me.

Comment: actually it does need to be a regexp, as I don't want to iterate over the array, which map obviously does I think.